# Find the minimum value of $x+y+z.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $x,y,z$ are nonegative  such that $(x - y)(y - z)(z - x) \geq 1.$ 
Find the minimum value  of  $x+y+z.$

Comment: I have edit the question.

Comment: Let $a=x-y,b=y-z,c=z-x,a+b+c=0,abc\ge1$ might be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, two among $x-y, y-z, z-x$ should be negative. WLOG let $a=x-y, b=z-y$ be positive numbers. Then $a(-b)(b-a) \ge 1 \iff a^2b \ge ab^2+1$ and we need the minimum of $a+b+3y$.    Obviously it is a good idea to set $y =0$, then we are left with minimising $a+b$.
$$a^2b-b^2a-1 \ge 0 \iff a \ge \frac{b^2+\sqrt{b^4+4b}}{2b}$$

So we minimise $a+b =\frac32b+ \dfrac{\sqrt{b^4+4b}}{2b}$, which by calculus and some algebra gives $b = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3\sqrt3-5}2}$.

Therefore we have the minimum (after some more algebra and help from @Semiclassical) as $\sqrt[3]2 \sqrt3$.

Comment: Asking WA to rationalize that last expression produces $2^{1/3} 3^{1/2}$ (which is quite simpler than I'd have expected.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I didn't notice that.  Thanks for helping in reducing the level of ugliness...

Comment: @Macavity please explane why we may set $y=0.$?

Comment: Because we have to minimise $a+b+3y$, with no constraint on $y$ other than it has to be non-negative.

Comment: @Semiclassical. The simplification to $\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt{3}$ is wrong since $\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt{3} \approx 2.182247273$  but it  must be about $2.263540673$ as was stated earlie.

Comment: @Leox: Where was this stated?

Comment: in the first version of solution of Macavity.

Comment: @Leox: I don't see that number in his first version, linked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/933973/1).

Comment: you are  right, Maple give the same result $\approx 2.18$